# Unable to run queries from a file using psql command line with docker exec

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker

I have a bash file should bring the postgres docker container online and then run a `.sql` file to create the databases. But it's throwing the error.

```
psql: error: provision-db.sql: No such file or directory
```

I have checked the path and the file exists at the same level of this bash script. Following is the content of my bash file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docker-compose up -d db

# Ensure the Postgres server is online and usable
until docker exec -i boohoo.postgres pg_isready --host="${POSTGRES_HOST}" --username="${POSTGRES_USER}"
do
    echo "."
    sleep 1
done

docker exec -i boohoo.postgres psql -h "${POSTGRES_HOST}" -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -a -q -f provision-db.sql
```

And this is the `provision-db.sql` file.

```
DROP DATABASE "boo-hoo";
CREATE DATABASE "boo-hoo";
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE "boo-hoo" TO postgres;
```

This is the part of `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  db:
    container_name: boohoo.postgres
    hostname: postgres.boohoo
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "15432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: "postgres"
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: "postgres"
```

Comment: How does the file get into the container?  Can you just run `psql` from the host without needing a `docker exec`?

Comment: `cat provision-db.sql | docker exec -i boohoo.postgres psql -h "${POSTGRES_HOST}" -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -a -q -f -` should do the trick asuming `provision-db.sql` is on your host and not in your container.

Comment: @ckaserer when I try this it doesn't allow me to type the db password when prompted and gives me `FATAL:  password authentication failed for user `

Comment: @DavidMaze if I run psql directly from the bash script how will it connect to the container db?

Comment: With `-h 127.0.0.1` to point at the current host, and via the first port number in the `ports:` line in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried following but didn't work. `psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 15432 -U postgres -a -q -f provision-db.sql`. It said is the server running and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 15432.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The short version

This works

```
cat provision-db.sql | docker exec -i boohoo.postgres bash -c 'psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -w -a -q -f -'
```

## The long version

multiple things here

### 1) why does following command not find the `provision-db.sql`?

```
docker exec -i boohoo.postgres psql -h "${POSTGRES_HOST}" -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -a -q -f provision-db.sql
```

because the provision-db.sql is on your host and not in your container. Therefore, when you execute the psql command inside the container it can not find the file

### 2) Why didn't my first solution work?

`cat provision-db.sql | docker exec -i boohoo.postgres psql -h "${POSTGRES_HOST}" -U "${POSTGRES_USER}" -a -q -f -`  should do the trick asuming provision-db.sql

That is due to the fact, that the variables `${POSTGRES_USER}` and `${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}` get evaluated on your host machine and I guess they are not set there. In addition, I forgot to specify the `-w` flag to avoid the password prompt

### 3) Why does that work?

```
cat provision-db.sql | docker exec -i boohoo.postgres bash -c 'psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -w -a -q -f -'
```

Well, let's go through it step by step.

First, we print the content of `provision-db.sql`, which resides on the host machine to stdout and pipe it to the next command via `|`.

`docker-exec` executes a command in the container specified (`boohoo.postgres`). By specifying the `-i` flag we allow the stdin from your host to go to stdin in the container <- that's important.

In the container, we execute `bash -c` which is just a wrapper to avoid evaluating the bash variables on the host. We want the variables from the container and by putting it into single quotes we can do that.

```
docker-exec boohoo.postgres bash -c "echo $POSTGRES_USER"
```

evaluates the host env variable named POSTGRES_USER.

```
docker-exec boohoo.postgres bash -c "echo $POSTGRES_USER"
```

evaluates the container env variable named POSTGRES_USER.

Next we just have to get our postgres command in order.

```
psql -U ${POSTGRES_USER} -w -a -q -f -
```

`-U` specifies the user
`-w` does not ask for password
`-q` do it quietly
`-f -` process whatever you get from stdin

Answer (score 0):

`-f` is an option for `psql` and not for `docker exec`, and `psql` is running inside the container, so it can only access the file if it is inside the container as well.

Comment: Well, thank you for explaining the problem but this answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Ok. But once you understand the problem, the solution is trivial.